# How can I process a python dictionary with callables?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a python directory whose values are to be evaluated separately.

So, for example, in the following non-working example I define

```
a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': foo(20)}
```

for which e.g.

```
def foo(max):
    """Returns random float between 0 and max."""
    return max*random.random()
```

and after processing of the dict I want to have e.g.

```
a_processes = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': 12.238746374}
```

The example does not work since the value of key `key3` is immediately  evaluated, and `foo(20)` is no callable. The way it could work would be to use something like

```
a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': foo}
```

but here `foo` will miss its arguments. One way to handle this would be to define the dict in the following way

```
a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': [foo, 20]}
```

with the following processing scheme

```
a_processed = dict([k,process(v)] for k,v in a.items())
```

in which `process` is a meaningful function checking if its argument is a list, or if the first element is a callable which gets called with the remaining arguments.

My question is about a better way/idea to implement my basic idea?

Comment: A dict is almost certainly the wrong data structure to use here. Do you want a different random value every time you try to access that key? Why not use a real class and add that behavior?

Comment: What is the problem with `a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': foo}`? Do you want a to still contain the values to input?

Comment: I would like to have a data structure, which can have fixed elements but also e.g. random elements, when I want it (NOT every time I print it or something).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often use an argument-free `lambda` here, just because I like the syntax:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x*100
... 
>>> a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': lambda: foo(20)}
>>> a
{'key3': <function <lambda> at 0x96ae80c>, 'key2': 42, 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> {k: v() if callable(v) else v for k,v in a.iteritems()}
{'key3': 2000, 'key2': 42, 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: Yes that is great. I think this is the solution to me problem, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a callable that'll apply a set of arguments to another callable:

```
from functools import partial

a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': partial(foo, 20)}
```

Now the `key3` value is a callable object; `a['key3']()` will in turn call `foo(20)` and return the result.

You'd still need to 'process' this dictionary (testing with the [`callable()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable):

```
{k: v() if callable(v) else v for k, v in a.iteritems()}
```

of course. If you are using Python 3, use `a.items()` instead.

A `functools.partial` setup let's you add additional arguments as needed (provided `foo()` supports them):

```
a['key3']('additional', arguments='accepted')
```

You could *even* create a dictionary subclass that does this automatically when accessing a key:

```
def CallablesDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super(CallablesDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        return value() if callable(value) else value
```

then define `a` as:

```
a = CallablesDict({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 42, 'key3': partial(foo, 20)})

print a['key3']  # calls foo(20)
```

Comment: Call it for example like this: `{k: (v() if hasattr(v, '__call__') else v) for (k, v) in a.items()}`

Comment: Yup - I won't bother posting now - I was going to suggest an overridden `dict` that implements `partial` upon a `__getitem__` etc...

Comment: @Jon: Good idea-ish, but leave the `partial` to the values I'd say.

Comment: Awesome - apart from me calling the `dict` - `blah` - your last edit would have been my answer :)

Comment: Although `callable` (which I was using) went away in 3.1 and came back in 3.2 or something

Comment: @JonClements: It was removed in 3.0, re-added in 3.2.

Comment: I was close :) I don't sleep with printed PEP's under my pillow :P